# Break multiple value cell into different rows via Apps Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm looking to split a cell that have multiple values separated by "\n" via App Script. Itried a few functions that were proposed but nothing seemed to work. Below you can see a sample format and desired outcome.

[image: Screenshot of current format versus desired output]

Thanks.

Comment: Do NOT share [spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455)/[images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) as the only source of data, to avoid closure of the question. Make sure to add input and expected output as **plain text table** to the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easier to copy/paste as well**. Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Comment: Is there any maximum amount of values that can appear on a single cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to split each cell value with `\n` using Google Apps Script.
- You want to put the split values in the vertical direction.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Please set your sheet name.
  const range = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow());
  const values = range.getValues().flatMap(([a]) => a ? a.split("\n").map(e => [e.trim()]) : []);
  range.offset(0, 1, values.length).setValues(values);
}
```

- When this script is run, the source values are retrieved from the column "A". And, the converted values are put in column "B".

#### Reference:

- [flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)